# how to get the value in the variable in the loop from ejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ejs

I am new to html and ejs. I am try to make a function of retweet, however, i can not fetch the origial tweet correctly(whatever retweet button I click, it shows the last tweet). I know the error is from   `<%= posts[i].tweets %>`, however, i cannot figure out how to fetch the corresponding tweets in each `<div>`. Anyone can help, thanks?

```
<div class="modal-body" panel panel-default><p><%= posts[i].tweets %></p></div>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <title> </title>



  </head>
  <body>
  <div >
       <% for(var i in posts) 
           {                     
        %>
      <b><a href="/user/<%= posts[i].user_id %>"><%= posts[i].username     %></a></b>
      <p  id="username1"><%= posts[i].tweets %></p>
  <div style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
        <button style="float: left;" class="btn btn-primary " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="">retweet</button>
        </div>          

    </div>
    <% 
            }  
%>

<div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">     
        <p style="color: red;"> <%=  locals.message %> </p>
          <form action="/retweet" method = "post">
            <textarea rows="5" style="float: center; margin-bottom: 0px;" name="tweet_content" class="form-control"></textarea>
            <div class="modal-body" panel panel-default><p><%= posts[i].tweets %></p></div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
             </div>
          </form>
      </div>
```

Comment: It is because the last `posts[i].tweets` is after the loop is over, so it retains the last value of `i`.

Comment: Do you really have a div before the doctype declaration?